# Tooltip doesn’t change when “add comment” link morphs into “add / show more comments”

Tags: bug, status-completed, tooltips

On first opening a question, the tooltip on an “add comment” link is *“ask author for clarification about this post”*, while on an “add / show more comments” link it is *“expand to show all comments on this post, or add one of your own”*.

But if “add comment” automagically morphs into “add / show more comments”, its tooltip doesn’t get updated at the same time, leaving it inconsistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The title for the "add / show more comments" will be updated when new comments are added after the next build.

Comment: Technically the first tooltip is also wrong when the post is your own (or it's implying you're schizophrenic), but that *may* be excessively pedantic on my part.

Comment: Looks good in rev 2012.5.10.2526