# No string to translate "Expand to show all comments on this post, or add one of your own"

Tags: bug, comments, localization, tooltips

On ruSO we [found](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/13048/176217) that the source string for *"Expand to show all comments on this post, or add one of your own"* is absent in translation database.

There's an old related post on MSE with clarification where this string is used [Tooltip doesn’t change when “add comment” link morphs into “add / show more comments”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132017/339911)